# How to call a method when model value updated using ngModelChange in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have used below code to call a method when model value has been changed using ngModelChange Event.

**app.component.ts:-**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="onModelChanged()"/>
     <input type="button" value="Submit" (click)="updateModelValue()"/>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  updateModelValue() {
     this.name = `Angular 2! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  onModelChanged() {
    alert('Model Changed');
  }
}
```

**Demo:-** https://plnkr.co/edit/4WosE8e3G822qbxVKJER?p=info

When I press any keys from keyboard, at that time ngModelChange Event has been fired. But when I update model value through button click Event, at that time ngModelChange Event has not been fired. How to call a method when model value has been changed using ngModelChange Event?

Comment: I don't understand. The method has been called on changed. You want to call onModelChanged() when you click on the button ?

Comment: @br.julien, Yes. I want to call onModelChanged() when I click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, based on your comments in the other answer (now deleted), the reason why `ngModelChange` event is not triggering when you `click` the button is because `ngModelChange` event is just an `Output()` property of the `ngModel` directive. So for this event to fire it requires the `ngModel` directive to be present on your html element and what it gets assigned to (as in `[(ngModel)]="name"`) will be its value which gets updated through `ngModelChange`. Hence, in your first `input` element, you have rightly used `ngModel` and its output property `ngModelChange` but in the `button` typed `input`, you can't expect the same behaviour.

Hope it makes sense. Please check these links, [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#outputs) & [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e3140ae888ac4037a5f119efaec7b1eaf8726286/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L161), for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger input event in the click handler, see below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
       <div>
       <input #nameInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="onModelChanged()"/>
       <input type="button" value="Submit" (click)="updateModelValue()"/>
       </div>
     `,
    })
export class App {
   name:string;
   @ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput:ElementRef;
   constructor() {
        this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    }
   updateModelValue() {
      const name = `Angular 2! v${VERSION.full}`;
      this.nameInput.nativeElement.value = name;
      this.nameInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
   }
   onModelChanged() {
      alert('Model Changed');
   }
 }
```